# Register a custom body handler in Spring

Tags: java, html, spring

I have an `Html` type which contains some HTML.

```
String name = "bob";
Html body = HTML."""
<p> Hello \{name} </p>
""";
```

How can I register this so that Spring knows how to handle it if I return a `ResponseEntity<Html>` from a controller?

Comment: set the [`produces`-field in the `@GetMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html#produces()) to [`TEXT_HTML_VALUE`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#TEXT_HTML_VALUE).

Comment: doing that still leads to this

Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class dev.mccue.html.Html] with preset Content-Type 'null']

Comment: Can you provide a [MRE], e.g. in form of a git repository?

Comment: Here you go https://github.com/bowbahdoe/spring-html-reproducer

Comment: You can replace `HTML` with `STR` and change `ResponseEntity<Html>` to `ResponseEntity<String>`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can call `.toString()` on the `Html`-object, and change the return-type from `ResponseEntity<Html>` to `ResponseEntity<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution that come to my mind that avoid writing a custom converter. I will discuss those two solutions (solutions 1 and 2) before discussing how to add a custom converter (solution 3).

---

### Solution 1: Work with `String`s instead of `Html`s

Instead of returning a `ResponseEntity<Html>`, we can return a `ResponseEntity<String>`. For this, we would:

- replace all occurrences of `HTML.` with `STR.`, and
- replace all returns types from `ResponseEntity<Html>` to `ResponseEntity<String>`

---

### Solution 2: Keep `Html`, but return a `ResponseEntity<String>`

We continue using `Html`, but we change all return types from `ResponseEntity<Html>` to `ResponseEntity<String>`. Finally, we call `toString()` on all `Html`-objects that are returned, e.g.:

```java
        return ResponseEntity.ok(
                HTML."""
                <ul>
                    \{rows}
                </ul>
                """
        )
        // this is the new line:
        .toString();
```

---

### Solution 3: Add a custom converter

---

##### Disclaimer

I have only tested the `write`-flow of the converter. The `read`-flow may or may not work.

---

To realize this, we need to implement the [`HttpMessageConverter` interface (`docs.spring.io`)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html). The implementation would look something like this:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import dev.mccue.html.Html;
import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

class HtmlConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<Html> {
    public static final HtmlConverter INSTANCE = new HtmlConverter();

    private HtmlConverter() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return Objects.equals(clazz, Html.class) && Objects.equals(mediaType, MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return Objects.equals(clazz, Html.class) && Objects.equals(mediaType, MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    }

    @Override
    public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
        return List.of(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    }

    @Override
    public Html read(Class<? extends Html> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        return Html.of(List.of(new String(inputMessage.getBody().readAllBytes())));
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Html html, MediaType contentType, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        outputMessage.getBody().write(STR."""
                <html>
                  <head></head>
                  <body>
                    \{html.toString()}
                  </body
                </html>""".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

Noteworthy is that we wrap the content of the `Html`-instance in a `html`- and a `body`-tag (and add an empty `header`-tag for good measurement). This might fail when the `html`-instance already has the `html`- and `body`-tag. The code is therefore only for demonstration purpose, and not production-ready.

Armed with thin implementation, we can register this custom converter. For this, we need a class that extends [`WebMvcConfigurer` (`docs.spring.io`)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html) to override method `configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageconverter<?>> messageConverters)`. We can (ab)use class `DemoApplication`for this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration // this is needed so that the class is loaded as configuration
public class DemoApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
        messageConverters.add(HtmlConverter.INSTANCE);
    }
}
```